# Problem with newtxtext and \textsuperscript

Tags: formatting, sharelatex, overleaf, times

I expercience problems with \textsuperscript and the package newtxtext. When I use \textsuperscript it is not "turned off" afterwards: MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
21\textsuperscript{th} century
\end{document}
```

yields [image]

```
21\textsuperscript{th} \textnormal{century}
```

yields [image]

It should not be necessary to "turn off" \textsuperscript. Correct? Any ideas?

Edit: I am using shareLatex with pdfLatex. Output of File List:

```
 scrbook.cls    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (type area)
newtxtext.sty    2017/05/28 v1.523
fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
t1ntxtlf.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
t1ntxsups.fd    2015/01/17 v1.0
```

Many Thanks
Benjamin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce the issue. What TeX distribution are you using? Can you please add `\listfiles` at the top of the example and show here the output you find in the log file after `*File list*`?

Comment: ShareLaTeX's TeX distribution is very out-of-date.

Comment: You are right. My fault. I replaced the file list with newtxtext instead of -math

Comment: _(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel on Overleaf.)_ Overleaf currently runs TeX Live 2017; sorry! We're aiming to upgrade later this year...

Comment: Minor unrelated nit: it’s “21st,” not “21th.”

Answer (score 2):

You're using `newtxtext` version 1.523 that has an error about `\textsuperscript`; you can fix it as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

% fix the error in version 1.523 of newtxtext
\let\latextextsuperscript\textsuperscript
\AtBeginDocument{\let\textsuperscript\latextextsuperscript}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

21\textsuperscript{th} century

\end{document}
```

You can see how the code in `newtxtext.sty` was actually fixed at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty?r1=44458&r2=45074&sortby=date

The package removed the wrong usage of `\textsu`, which is the same I do in the suggested patch.

Comment: @Benjamin The best is, of course, typing `21th` and avoiding the Victorian age superscript.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem with Overleaf. ShareLaTeX and Overleaf are currently using a very old TeX distribution.

It seems to me that `\textsuperscript` in this case doesn't have any argument, it works like `\bfseries`, etc. Therefore, the following code can solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
21{\textsuperscript th} century
\end{document}
```

You can also do something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeatletter
\let\@mycommand\textsuperscript
\renewcommand\textsuperscript[1]{{\@mycommand #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
21\textsuperscript{th} century
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solution works for me. Good to know that shareLatex uses an old TeX distribution. But the advantages in terms of collaboration and working from different computers with different systems: mac windows is more important to me.

Comment: @Benjamin Of course ShareLaTeX is not bad. That is the starting point of LaTeX in my life. However, because it is an online platform, it is very difficult to update TeX Live there, that is the point of my sentence.